# Как вернуть окна в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Случайно все сбил в Eclipse, а точнее сказать окна все куда то исчезли. Перерыл все настройки.

Может кто знает, как вернуть консоль?
Как вернуть окно сервака?
Как вообще все вернуть? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: View в меню????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все сам решил и нашел. можно как описано выше, но если нет такого меню как у меня на скрине, то необходимо, чтобы вернуть server окно и console окно (именно такой был вопрос) нажать на Window-> Show View-> Other и в поиске ввести console затем двойным нажатием и консоль восстановиться, также и server окна все станут на места. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

См. меню Window -> Show view....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, даже не представляю как можно ещё улучшить данный ответ, разве что скриншот добавить. После открытия указанного пункта меню все становится предельно понятно - там есть перечень всех тех окон (и других тоже), о которых пишет автор вопроса. Выбирая пункты меню можно открывать и закрывать эти окна.

Comment: у меня нет такого в меню

Comment: нашел ... емае ...  надо нажать other и там искать ... а как сервак на место вернуть ?

Comment: Там же в Other... должно быть Server

Comment: да решил.. спасибо вам Игорь ..